# In Ant-Man Movie, How did the two cops get to the house so fast

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

Ant man chases yellow jacket to the helicopter. The helicopter flies for some time while they fight in it. Then they drop out of the helicopter with a suitcase, lands in some random house's swimming pool. House member tries to call cops but was stopped by yellow jacket. Ant man jumps on yellow jacket, and they fight for about 10 seconds. Ant man smashes yellow jacket into a fly trap. Just as ant man is about to finish him off, 2 cops magically shows up.

How did the two cops catch up to the helicopter and finds the random house and stop ant-man from saving the world so fast? How? How?

Comment: Their cruiser had *plot-device engines* installed that morning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The policemen were following the helicopter from the ground.

[image]

Although it's a bit of stretch that they know to head to *that particular house* (e.g. instead of continuing to following the now out-of-control helicopter), you do have the fact that the falling case was shooting lasers out in all directions. That seems like the sort of thing that's worthy of investigation, even ignoring the loud explosions and screaming coming from the house and its running occupants.

[image]